# Reading the same data from stdin multiple times in C

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, scanf

I'm writing a cache simulator in C that's based on trace files, which I want to pipe into the program via stdin.  These trace files can be up to 15 billion lines long, so I don't want to store them anywhere in active memory.  I want to run the simulation multiple times for different memory configurations from one call using a configuration file which is specified in the input to the program.  The program call should look like this:

`cat | (trace file) ./MemorySimulator -f (config file)`

Right now, the way the program runs is that it uses the config file to set the parameters of a simulation then reads the piped in formatted data from stdin using scanf() until it reaches the end of the trace file.  It then proceeds to the next configuration setting from the config file and tries to read data from the trace file over again.  This process continues until the various configuration options have been exhausted.

The problem I'm running into is that once I run through the trace file once, I'm unable to capture the data again for the following memory configuration from the config file.

Is there a way to recycle the pipe data within my C program so that I can run the simulation multiple times from a single program execution?  So far, I haven't been able to find a way to accomplish this.

Comment: you could try `cat file file file file file | ./MemorySimulator -f config_file` (which would, for example, cat the data file 5 times in a row)

Comment: @arcticmac how would you detect then the file ends?

Comment: tried that - it pipes the file into the first simulation the number of times you specify it in the command line and the remaining simulations get no input.  This is probably because the scanf() function doesn't read an EOF until you finish reading the trace file x number of times from cat.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin oops, missed that detail.  I was kinda assuming you might be able to infer that from the structure of the data, but yeah, you only get one EOF.

Answer (score 2):

No, that doesn't work. That's the very nature of a pipe.

You cannot have the demand that data isn't cached and at the same time that it can be re-requested.

In a pipe, one the data has been written, it is gone, so you haveto store it somewhere in order not to get lost.

The only way you can accomplish this is to "imitate" the behaviour of the other program - which should be trivial in the `cat` case.

To be exact, your code is a very good example for the famous UUOC (Unneecessary Use of `cat`).

If you are requested to read from stdin - well, that hasn't to be a pipe. Instead of

```
cat file | program
```

you can do

```
program < file
```

and this doesn't give you a pipe, but direct access to the file, including the ability to seek.

You could use this if possible, and if not, either cache the data yourself or refuse to run.

This, however, doesn't work if you are requested to accept *all* kinds of standard input.

Comment: Is there a way to find out where the pipe is coming from within C (grab the file name) and then reopen a new pipe?

Comment: @ChrisHack no. The “file” might just be terminal input. Once it’s gone, it’s gone.

Comment: So, is there another way to pipe the file data in through standard input that I could call from within the C program?

Comment: That's an interesting solution to the problem... I would like to try it, however I ultimately need to be able to read files that are in gzip format.  I think this is the reason that I was using the pipe initially (it was suggested that we use the zcat utility to read the files).  The reason for this is that the trace files are about 10-15 GB zipped and >40GB unzipped... would the proposed solution (program < file) work with that?

Comment: Also, how would one seek through the file from within the program using the program < file call?  I've never seen that one before

Comment: @Chris Alas, that would not work, as this is the same as the initial solution. This would only work if you'd implement the (and all other) unpacking algorithms as well. And then, it would prevent `wget http://filesource | zcat | simulate`. So you'd lose a lot of flexibility. This would be undesired. With `program < file`, you'd just call `seek(0, ...)` and it would either work (return 0, indicating success) or fail (return < 0, indicating failure). In the latter case, you'd either cache the data (what are 40 GB of RAM nowadays? :-P) or refuse to process it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> Is there a way to recycle the pipe data within my C program so that I can run the simulation multiple times from a single program execution?

If you are open to using the trace file as an input argument to the program, you can accomplish what you want.

Instead of

```
cat <tracefile> | ./MemorySimulator -f (config file)
```

you can use:

```
./MemorySimulator <tracefile> -f (config file)
```

In `main`, use `fopen` to open the trace file. Once you are done using it for one configuration, rewind using `frewind` and reuse the `FILE*` for the next configuration.

You can also use `fopen/fclose` on the trace file for each configuration.

Comment: Normally, this is the route I would take to accomplish this, however this is a school assignment and the specifications for it are "Write your simulator program to get the trace file information from standard input," which is why I've got this conundrum...

Comment: To be more specific with the project specifications, they read: "Write your simulator program to get the trace file information from standard input. The program
should also accept an optional configuration file from the command line."

Answer (score 0):

Given your comments that you are required to read your data from `stdin` (and, I presume, cannot require `stdin` to be directly redirected from a file), you have little choice than to cache the data yourself. Since that data is more than 40GB, the cache better be a disk file.

What I'd do is, on the first pass, open a temporary file for read/write and as you read from a `FILE*` variable set equal to `stdin`, also write the data to your temporary file. At the end of the first pass, copy your temporary file fp to your input fp.

Now for the remaining passes, you can start be rewinding your input (temporary) file and read it for input.

You can use your loop counter to determine what you need to do each pass.

Here's an overview of this code:

```
infp = stdin;
for (loop = 0; loop < NUM_LOOPS; loop++) {
    if (loop == 0) {
        tmpfp = fopen("tmpfile.tmp", "w");
        //check for errors here
    }
    for (;;) {
        num_read = read(infp, buf, sizeof(buf));
        // check for EOF here and break if so
        if (loop == 0) {
            num_written = write(tmpfp, buf, num_read);
            //check for write errors here
        }

        // Main input processing code
    }

    if (loop == 0) {
        infp = tmpfp;
    }
    rewind(infp);
}
```