# Write in stdin from inside a program in C

Tags: c, stdin

I am trying to open a .txt file and put its contents in the standard input. I know you can do:

```
myapp < input.txt
```

but i want to use the same content several times inside the program and i think that with this method the stdin content is consumed and can not be used again.

I want to test a function that reads from stdin, just as an example of what i am trying:

```
void myFunction(int number)
{
    // The function already writen reads from stdin using the argument.
}

void fillStdin(void)
{
    FILE* myFile;
    myFile = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

    // Put the content of the file in stdin

    fclose(myFile);
}


int main(void)
{
    int myArray[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        fillStdin();
        myFunction(myArray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have even a small example of what you have tried so far?  I think you mean read file, and write the contents to stdout?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: Short answer: WHAT??? Long answer: What on earth is the question here???

Comment: @jpw is it possible to reuse the stdin content?

Comment: @barakmanos he wants to read `stdin` multiple times. But it isn’t possible.

Comment: Im assuming what you mean is you want to be able to reuse the content you're inputting into the text file? If that's the case, why not just store the content in an array?

Comment: @Rage i am trying to do it this way to test a program that in the end will read from stdin.

Comment: @wallek876 It would depend on what you do with it inside the program I guess.

Comment: if you read stdin into a storage buffer, then you can re-use it as many times as you want to.

Comment: @jpw the program just uses `scanf()` to get the content.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to *optionnaly* use a file, and if no file given read from stdin ?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29763277/reading-the-same-data-from-stdin-multiple-times-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to modify your code. Just execute your program as this (assuming you are using Unix):

```
while true; do cat input.txt; done | myapp
```

This will feed `input.txt` to your `stdin` over and over again. Take into account that you will need to figure out when you have reached the end of each recurrence, as `stdin` will never EOF this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the program takes the input all the times and handles it correctly but when it finishes it is kind of a stuck. I wonder if there is also a way to feed the input a fixed number of times, maybe then it will not get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily write into stdin like so:

```
char *buffer = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
... //get file contents etc.
write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, bufsize); //the important part.
```

you'll need to include unistd.h and I don't think it's portable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example of how you can read stdin into a storage buffer, and into a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define MAXLINELENGTH 4096

FILE *fin;
char fileName[] = "temp.txt";

void processLine(char *line)
{

    fin = fopen(fileName, "a");
    fputs(line, stdout);
    fputs(line, fin);
    fclose(fin);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    char line[1024];
    char input[MAXLINELENGTH];

    printf("enter continuous text, and ~ when finished\n");

    while (fgets(line, 1024, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        processLine(line);
        if(strstr(line, "~")) //enter a "~" to exit program
              return 0;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Once you have the file, you can read from it using `fopen()` and `fgets()`, then write it back out to stdout.